# add more white space in content pseudo class

Tags: html, css, pseudo-class

How can I add more space using content pseudo class

I am using below code to add single space.

```
h3:before{content:" "}
```

I need to add more space by using content.

PS: No addition in html pls

Comment: You can't unless you use `&nbsp;`, and even then, I'm not sure if browsers will support that coming from CSS, or if they will just escape the reference and print it as it appears.

Comment: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/beforeafter.html
its supported in all major browsers but what exactly do you need to do?
make space before your h3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using some padding-right instead of spaces?

```
h3 {
    padding-right: 10px
}
```

Answer (score 0):

............................................

Used to **margin** or **padding** in your `after`

as like  this

```
h3:before{content:"";
margin-left:40px;
}
```

***[Demo](http://tinkerbin.com/kAbUIlRu)***

Answer (score 0):

If you just wanna make space before your first line of text in that why dont you use

```
h3:first-line{padding:0 0 0 40px;} or
h3{padding:0 0 0 40px;}
```

These "padding" are shortcuts for

```
padding-top padding-right padding-bottom padding-left
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution to achieve this is to use the "word-spacing" property to increase the space that each space is using.

For example `word-spacing: 10px;` will make each space take up 10 pixels.

This allows you to use a single pseudo element with multiple words, and still add seperation where `margin` and `padding` won't be able to assist.

*Example*

```
.my-class::before {
    content: 'One Two Three';
    word-spacing: 10px;
}
```

---

If you require more control, you could also escape your spaces in the `content` property, and use `white-space: pre;` to allow the escaped spaces to be displayed (as they will be ignored by default on most elements).

*Example*

```
.my-class::before {
    content: 'One \ \ Two \ \ Three';
    white-space: pre;
}
```

---

References:

[MDN Web Docs: word-spacing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-spacing)

[MDN Web Docs: white-space](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space)

[CSS Character Escape Sequences](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/css-escapes)